# What could C/C++ "lose" if they defined a standard ABI?

Tags: c++, c, standards, abi

The title says everything. I am talking about C/C++ specifically, because both consider this as "implementation issue". I think, defining a standard interface can ease building a module system on top of it, and many other good things.
*What could C/C++ "lose" if they defined a standard ABI?*

Comment: ABI is application binary interface. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface

Comment: Even C does not have a fully fledged standard ABI. It has a standard ABI for each system based on the standard lib for that system.

Comment: Martin: what did you mean when you typed "C" in that comment? I presume you meant something else, maybe something like "a compiler"?

Comment: On most platforms, there is a standard ABI for C programs, and all the C compilers on the platform conform to that ABI.  This means you can use different C compilers and yet use the same standard C library.  In contrast, on a single system, the C++ compilers do not share a common ABI.  This allows the different compilers to do things differently - but means that code compiled by one C++ compiler cannot use the libraries produced by another.

Comment: @Martin: No, C doesn't have a standard ABI for each system. It's pretty much reversed. Most, but not all systems have a C ABI defined. The ISO SC22 WG14 (aka the C committee) doesn't define them; the platform "owners" define them.

Comment: @MSalters: That is what I was trying to say. The compiler does not define it, the compiler inherits it from the standard lib (which may not even be written in C). But the compiler must generate code that is binary compatible (and thus conform to the ABI used by the standard lib). I was not aware it was defined by the platform, but that makes sense as the platform (I assume Hardware/OS) then determines how the standard lib is built. In summary I was trying to say (but badly) the compiler implements the C ABI defined by the platform.

Comment: @MArtin: the "standard lib" is part of the "C implementation" - the ISO standard describes the combination of preprocessor, compiler, linker, libraries and other parts that together behave as mandated. Therefore the compiler can generate code that matches the standard lib installed together with that compiler. The ABI shared between them is therefore a prodcut-specific ABI. This is not just theory: the standard lib of MSVC9 is specific to the MSVC9 compiler (due to buffer overflow protection checks)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The freedom to implement things in the most natural way on each processor.

I imagine that c in particular has conforming implementations on more different architectures than any other language. Abiding by a ABI optimized for the currently common, high-end, general-purpose CPUs would require unnatural contortions on some the odder machines out there.

Comment: Very much agreed.  On many platforms, you'd like to pass arguments in registers for speed, but you don't want to use all the registers for argument passing.  But different platforms have different numbers of registers.  Some platforms have no floating-point registers at all.  Any completely general ABI would be suboptimal on nearly every platform.

Comment: One of the reasons C became so popular was because it didn't specify a standard ABI (IIRC, Pascal did).  Thus, compiler writers could do whatever worked best.  Initially, everyone did pretty much the same thing in terms of stack framing, but later, for architectures like DSPs, they started to specify ways to pack function arguments into registers, greatly reducing the number of instructions and memory transactions needed for a function call.

Comment: I remember an architecture which had a 32-register file visible to the programmer, but implemented it in hardware as a 512-register block with a sliding window.  r0-r7 were parameters passed to a called function, r8-r15 were function locals, r16-r23 were parameters passed in from the function's caller, and r24-r31 were globals, including the stack pointer.  r24-31 would always point to the same place, but the others were mapped through a window that would slide down 16 registers with a function call (mapping the caller's r0-7 to the callee's r16-r23), then slide back 16 on return.

Comment: @Mike: That sounds very much like SPARC, but different generations had different amounts of HW registers before they spilled over to RAM.

Comment: “The freedom to implement things in the most natural way on each processor.”: ABIs are already architecture dependent. The ia32 ABI is not the same as the ia64 ABI, either for Linux, Max OS or Windows.

Comment: @Hibou57: This question doesn't recognize that fact.

Answer (score 10):

Backwards compatibility on every platform except for the one whose ABI was chosen.

Comment: Alternately, whoever standardizes this could refuse to choose any existing ABI (presumably because nobody could agree on a competitor's), and then nobody would have backward compatibility.

Comment: And then nobody would adhere to the standard.

Comment: We don't have backward compatibility now. Every time a compiler is updated you may be required to re-compile all your libs to conform to the new ABI it defines.

Comment: @Martin: If you have to do that, you have a malicious compiler vendor and you should stop giving them money for their product. There's no excuse for ABI breaking.

Comment: @Stephen: GCC did 3 times in the previous version. 2.9x -> 3.0 (break: New ABI) 3.0 -> 3.1 (break Bug Fix) 3.1 -> 3.2 (break Something else)

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't happen, I'm saying that it shouldn't.  The reasons for doing it don't justify the complications of breaking compatibility.

Comment: Also: I *don't* give GNU money for their product ;-)

Comment: Yeah, that does make it a little harder to negotiate better behavior from the GCC maintainers =)

Comment: There may have been problems in C++ with GCC, but I don't recall any problems with C.

Answer (score 9):

Basically, everyone missed that one of the C++14 proposals actually DID define a standard ABI. It was a standard ABI specifically for libraries that used a subset of C++. You define specific sections of "ABI" code (like a namespace) and it's required to conform to the subset.

Not only that, it was written by THE Herb Stutter, C++ expert and author the "Exceptional C++" book series.

The proposal goes into many reasons why a portable ABI is difficult, as well as novel solutions.

https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/05/n4028

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4028.pdf

Note that he defines a "target platform" to be a combination of CPU architecture (x64, x86, ARM, etc), OS, and bitness (32/64).

So the goal here, is actually having C++ code (Visual Studio) be able to talk to other C++ code (GCC, older Visual Studio, etc) on the same platform. It's not a goal of a universal ABI that lets cellphones libraries run on your Windows machine.

This proposal was NOT ratified in C++14, *however*, it was moved into the "Evolution" phase of C++17 for further discussion/iteration.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/5894415f-be62-4bc0-81c5-3956e82276f3/entry/c_14_is_ratified_the_view_from_the_june_2014_c_standard_meeting?lang=en

So as of January 2017, my fingers remain crossed.

Comment: Given that the vast majority of platforms where C and C++ used are identical except for a small number of "parameters", it would make sense to recognize features that are common to identifiable subsets of platforms.  I don't see such a thing as flying with the Committee, though, even though it would solve a lot of problems.

Comment: In 1988, there was no standard but compiler writers sought to be compatible with each other even when no standard required it.  If the Standard had recognized conventions, but also recognized that they would interfere with optimization, it could have introduced new ways of achieving the same semantics without affecting optimization and then deprecated the old ones.  Further, if the language included a type "32 bit unsigned int stored as four bytes big-endian", as well as variants of other sizes, signedness, endianness, etc. that would have made the language more useful on machines...

Comment: ...with weird int sizes, because such machines could run code that uses those types when appropriate more efficiently than they could run code which needs to exchange octet-based data with other systems and has to work around the lack of such types.

Comment: I would love to hear if there is any update on this topic as of May 2017. Was it ratified for C++17?

Answer (score 8):

Rather than a generic ABI for all platforms (which would be disastrous as it would only be optimal for only one platform). The standard's committee could say that each platform will conform to a specific ABI.

But: Who defines it (the first compiler through the door?). In which case they get an excessive competitive advantage. Or a committee after 5 years of compilers (which would be another horrible idea).

Also it does not give the compiler leaway to do further research into new optimization strategies, you would be stuck with the tricks available at the point where the standard was defined.

Comment: Many platforms support multiple ABIs, even within the same program.  What's problematic in many cases is knowing whether an implementation will guarantee behaviors which would naturally follow from the ABI.  For example, if an implementation specifies that 16-bit values are stored as two bytes little-endian and 32-bit values are stored as four bytes little-endian, those two statements together would define a natural behavior for `uint32_t x=0x12345678; *(uint16_t*)&x = 0x4321;` but that doesn't mean implementations using that ABI will actually behave that way.

Answer (score 8):

The C (or C++) language specifications define the source language. They don't care about the processor running it (A C program could even be interpreted by a human slave, but that would be unethical and not cost-effective).

The ABI is by definition something about the target system. It is related to the processor and the system (and the existing libraries following the ABI).

In the past, it did happen that some processors had proprietary (i.e. undisclosed) specification (even their machine instruction set was not public), and they had a non-public ABI which was followed by a compiler (respecting more or less the language standard).

Defining a programming language don't require the same skill sets as defining the ABI.

<sup>You could even define a newer ABI for an existing processor, but that requires a lot of work (patching the compiler, recompiling every thing, including C & C++ standard libraries and all utilities and libraries that you need) so is generally useless.</sup>

Answer (score 6):

Execution speed would suffer drastically on a majority of platforms. So much so that it would likely no longer be reasonable to use the C language for a number of embedded platforms. The standards body could be liable for an antitrust suit brought by the makers of the various chips not compatible with the ABI.

Comment: Run for your life, they've got Lawyers!

Answer (score 4):

Well, there wouldn't be one standard ABI, but about 1000. You would need one for every combination of OS and processor architecture.

Initially, nothing would be lost. But eventually, somebody would find some horrible bug and they would either fix it, breaking the ABI, or leave it, causing problems.

I think that the situation right now is fine. Any OS is free to define an ABI for itself (and they do), which makes sense. It should be the job of the OS to define its ABI, not the C/C++ standard.

Comment: Or the developer, for those developing code that runs without an OS.

Answer (score 2):

C always had a standard ABI, which is even the one used for any most standard ABI (I mean, the C ABI is the ABI of choice, when different languages or systems has to bind to each others). The C ABI is kind of common ABI of others ABIs. C++ is more complex although extending and thus based on C, and indeed, a standard ABI for C++ is more challenging and may present issues to the freedom a C++ compiler have for its own implementation of the target machine code. However, it seems to actually have a standard ABI; see [Itanium C++ ABI](http://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html).

So the question may not be that much “what could they loose?”, but rather “what do they loose?” (if ever they really loose something).

**Side note:** needed to keep in mind ABIs are always architecture and OS dependant. So if what was meant by “Standard ABI” is “standard across architectures and platforms”, then there may never has been or be such thing, but communication protocols.