# How to resolve the symbol of "printf" instead of "_printf" on win32 console?

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, dll

test platform is windows 32bit.

So basically I want to assembly + link a snippet of assembly code in these commands:

```
nasm -fwin32 test.s
cl test.obj /link msvcrt.lib
```

It says :

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol printf
```

In my code I do have function call like this:

```
call printf
```

So I changed all of these into

```
call _printf
```

and it works.

I am not familiar with programming on windows, but is there any way to resolve the external symbol of **printf** ?

Because I am doing some automatically transform task, and transformation of all the function calls with **_** begin should be very tedious...

Can anyone give me some help..? Thank you!

Comment: This article on calling conventions might be of use to you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2b2ssfy.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSVCRT, like everything compiled with Visual C++, exports `cdecl` functions [using an underscore prefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks.aspx). For your own libraries, you can [override this behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988084/cdecl-forcing-prefix-with-underscore), but since MSVCRT is not your library, you can't change that.

You really are going to have to make your assembly calls use the underscore name. But nasm has an option, [`--prefix`](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11/html/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.1.27), which makes this easier: `--prefix _`. (Thanks to Frank Kotler for mentioning this.)

Comment: Nasm has a feature... one of the few options that require two hyphens: `--prefix _` that will put an underscore on anything declared `global` or `extern` if that helps.

Comment: @Frank Nice, thanks for that info. Do you want me to fold that into my answer?

Comment: Sure! Go for it! Might as well note that for OpenWatcom: `--postfix _` - yeah, OpenWatcom uses a trailing underscore...