# Resolving undefined symbols externally

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86, masm, masm32

Beginner level in Assembly.

The error I receive in Visual Studio is:

**1>File2.asm(27): error A2006: undefined symbol : sprintf**

**1>File2.asm(28): error A2006: undefined symbol : MessageBoxA**

File 1 is what handles calculations

File 2 is what prints result to a window.

The line the handles print instructions is:

```
   invoke sprintf, addr szBuf, offset $interm, eax, edx
   invoke MessageBoxA, 0, addr szBuf, offset _title, 0
   invoke ExitProcess, 0
```

What am I doing wrong to the cause it not to build?

Is it because sprintf is a C function?

**File1.asm**

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none  

 PUBLIC squareroot
 PUBLIC szBuf
 include     \masm32\include\windows.inc
include     \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include     \masm32\include\msvcrt.inc

includelib  \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib  \masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib

.data
  _title db "Result",13,10,0
  $interm db "%0.4f","+","%0.5f",13,10,0
   Aval REAL8 1.000
   Bval REAL8 -2.000
   Cval REAL8 19.000
   _fourval REAL8 4.000
   $Tvalueinc REAL4 1.0,2.00,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0,13.0,14.0
   $sampleval real10 4478784.0
   $Powercounter dd ?
   squareroot dq ?
   $prevCW dw ?
   $Tagword dd ?
   $INT1 dq ?


  EXTERN Finished:PROC


.code
szBuf:

add eax,4

fstcw $prevCW
fwait
fld Bval ;  [loads first instance of b]]
fmul Bval ; [b*b = b^2]
fld Aval ;[Load a (a*c)]
fmul Cval ;(a*c)
fmul _fourval ;[4*a*c]
fsubp;[b^2-4*a*c]
ftst ;compare ST(0) with 0.0
fstsw ax ;[store camparison results in ax]
sahf ;transfer flags from AH register
mov ecx, 0004h


jb _negative ;jump if <0
fsqrt ;sqrt(b^2-4*a*c)



_negative:
fchs 
fsqrt
fld $sampleval
xor eax,eax
$repeat:


inc eax
push eax
mov ax, $prevCW
push eax
fldcw [esp]
fld $Tvalueinc[ecx]
fdivp
fld st(0)
FRNDINT
fcomp
fstsw ax
Sahf
fnstenv    [ebx-10h]
movzx   eax, word ptr [ebx-10h + 8h]
fldcw $prevCW
pop eax
pop eax

jz $repeat
dec eax
cmp eax, $Powercounter
add ecx, 0004h
mov eax, dword ptr squareroot
mov edx, dword ptr squareroot[0004h]
jmp Finished
END szBuf
```

**File2.asm**

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
option casemap:none

PUBLIC Finished
PUBLIC ExitProcess

include     \masm32\include\windows.inc
include     \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include     \masm32\include\msvcrt.inc

includelib  \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib  \masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib

.data
   _title db "Result",13,10,0
   $interm db "%0.4f","+","%0.5f",13,10,0


.code

Finished:  




   invoke sprintf, addr szBuf, offset $interm, eax, edx
   invoke MessageBoxA, 0, addr szBuf, offset _title, 0
   invoke ExitProcess, 0

END
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the function [`sprintf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa272937(v=vs.60).aspx) from MSVCRT.lib, which is a C library, and its exported name is [prefixed by an underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21028569/1305969). Hence it's `_sprintf` instead of `sprintf`.

The function [`MessageBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx) is contained in `user32.lib` which you didn't incluce, so the linker could not find it.

There's also the function [`wsprintf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647550(v=vs.85).aspx) in user32.lib which is quite similar to `sprintf`, so if you want to save space and decrease the size of the file you can use that one instead.

`sprintf` and `wsprintf` both use the [C calling convention](http://masm32.com/board/index.php?topic=3327.0) (contrary to the STDCALL convention set as default in the `.model flat,stdcall` line).

> Note  It is important to note that wsprintf uses the C calling convention (_cdecl), rather than the standard call (_stdcall) calling convention. As a result, it is the responsibility of the calling process to pop arguments off the stack, and arguments are pushed on the stack from right to left. In C-language modules, the C compiler performs this task.

But `INVOKE`(more precise: [its `PROTO` directive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/73407/using-proto-and-invoke-to-call-a-c-function-from-masm)) does take care of that so don't worry now.

To fix the errors change/add these lines to your code:

```
include     \masm32\include\user32.inc
includelib  \masm32\lib\user32.lib
...
invoke _sprintf, addr szBuf, offset $interm, eax, edx
```