# Cython dynamic library linking

Tags: python, dll, cython

I'm actually trying to link an existing C library to my Cython program.

I have access to the entrypoint header (.h) of the library with all functions declared as:

```
EXPORT_API int _stdcall LibFunction();
```

I suppose the `EXPORT_API` is used to create the dll with `__declspec(dllexport)`...

I also have access to the .lib and .dll files.

I've tried to use this function with the usual `cdef extern from`of Cython:

```
cdef extern from "include\\entrypoint.h":
    int LibFunction()

def c_LibFunction():
    LibFunction()
```

And I'm using the following setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

NAME = 'testlib'
REQUIRES = ['cython']
SRC_DIR = 'testlib'
PACKAGES = [SRC_DIR]

INCLUDE_DIR = 'testlib\include'
LIB_DIR = 'testlib\lib'

ext = Extension(SRC_DIR + '.wrapped',
                [SRC_DIR + '/wrapped.pyx'],
                include_dirs=[INCLUDE_DIR],
                library_dirs = [LIB_DIR],
                libraries=['cfunc', 'MyLib']
                )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup(
            install_requires=REQUIRES,
            packages=PACKAGES,
            name=NAME,
            ext_modules=[ext],
            cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext}
            )
```

But when I compile my Cython `python setup.py build_ext` I get an unresolved external reference:

`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_LibFunction`

As I found on [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397423/dll-lnk2019-error-unresolved-external-error-imp#17433783) it seems so be a question of static or dynamic library linking.

I think it comes from the setuptools compiling options, I tried to investigate using distutils [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html) and Cython [documentation](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html).

The thing is, I also tried to do my own C library (cfunc.lib, a static one) and I managed to use function in it the same way I described above.

I also used `DUMPBIN` on MyLib.lib and I found the symbo `int __cdecl LibFunction(void)`and as expected, the `__imp_` is not in the symbol.

It someone has an idea of what's going on, why it's going on and how I can solve my problem it could be really helpful !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution so I post it if someone needs help in the future !

I work on Windows using Visual Studio to compile my code.

Even if I created my `cfunc`project as a Visual C++ project, it didn't compile as a C++ project but as a C project so it worked by default (it only has a .c and a .h files).

My `entrypoint.h` only contains C-style function declaration but the dll is compiled as a C++ project, that's why it couldn't work, the name mangling was bad.

So I just added `language = 'c++'`in my `setup.py`

Comment: Hi, I follow your solution and solve the compiling problem, however, when i import the compiled .pyd file, it raises error "DLL load failed while importing use_cmaths: The specified module could not be found", any ideas?