# Create C/C++ library in Xcode and import it in C# .NETCore

Tags: c#, c++, objective-c, xcode, .net-core

I am trying to write an C/C++ dynamic library in Xcode, compile it to an `.dylib` library package (or whatever you call that) and `[DLLImport]` it in .NET Core.

Little background on why: A Chinese company develops a device for us, for integrating their device in our software they wrote a demo library in Borland C++ to test the integration and that worked out.

Now I want to know if it is possible for us to import an C++ library, written in Xcode, into our application as well, using .NET Core or Xamarin.

Now I am a rooky at C/C++ and I am a bit new to the cross platform solutions provided by Microsoft. But according to [this github question](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/343) `DLLImport` should work on Mac. Now I am wondering how.

So, in my best effort to write a C++ library:

**ApiFunc.h**

```
#ifndef ApiFuncH
#define ApiFuncH

double mean(double x, double y);

typedef void (*SignalHandler)(int signum);
typedef int (*OPEN_IMAGE_FILE)(char*);

extern OPEN_IMAGE_FILE open(char *FileName);
extern  SignalHandler signal(int signum, SignalHandler handler);

class TAPIFunc
{
public:
    int OpenImageFile(char *FileName);
};
#endif
```

**ApiFunc.cpp**

```
#pragma hdrstop

#include "ApiFunc.h"

double mean(double x, double y){
    return x * y;
}

int TAPIFunc::OpenImageFile(char *FileName)
{
    return 5;
}
```

Just trying some different methods out there...
So this compiles to a `libtestmachw.dylib`

I import that into my .NET Core console application:

```
    [DllImport("libtestmachw.dylib", EntryPoint = "mean")]
    private static extern double mean(double x, double y);

    [DllImport("libtestmachw.dylib")]
    private static extern int OPEN_IMAGE_FILE(string fileName);

    [DllImport("libtestmachw.dylib")]
    private static extern int OpenImageFile(string fileName);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        Console.WriteLine("Let's try to communicate with a Mac dylib library");
        Console.WriteLine("We are now going to invole function 'mean' of libtestmacw.dylib");
        try
        {
            double result = mean(2, 4);
            Console.WriteLine("yes, we made it! Result:" + result);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Opes that didn't work!");
            Console.WriteLine(e);

        }
        Console.WriteLine("We are now going to invole function 'OPEN_IMAGE_FILE' of libtestmacw.dylib");
        try
        {
            int result = OPEN_IMAGE_FILE("SomeFile.png");
            Console.WriteLine("yes, we made it! Result:" + result);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Opes that didn't work!");
            Console.WriteLine(e);

        }
        Console.WriteLine("We are now going to invole function 'OpenImageFile' of libtestmacw.dylib");
        try
        {
            int result = OpenImageFile("SomeFile.png");
            Console.WriteLine("yes, we made it! Result:" + result);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Opes that didn't work!");
            Console.WriteLine(e);

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

When running this, on Mac, I get an `System.EntryPointNotFoundException`

> Unable to find an entry point named 'OpenImageFile' in DLL 'libtestmachw.dylib'.

I just want to test if I can import functions inside a .NETCore application, from their on I can instruct the Chinese company to get their code compiled into a `.dylib`. Who can help me out or point me into the right direction?

This Microsoft page shows it is possible, so I am guess I am doing something wrong at the c/c++ side? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop

Comment: Try wrapping the code in the `.h`-file in an `extern "C" { ...your code... }` block. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8534917/3740093

Comment: You might also have to add `__declspec(dllexport)` to the function (like seen in the link I shared above).

Comment: @VisualVincent `__declspec(dllexport)` is a windows-only thing and not needed on other platforms.

Comment: @MartinUllrich : Wasn't aware of that, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You cannot call C++ functions, only C functions. Also, these functions need to be exported using standard C conventions, so in C++ you might need to add an `extern "C"` as well.

The problem in your sample is that `TAPIFunc::OpenImageFile` is a C++ function that cannot be imported.

For example, this function defined in a `.cpp` file can be used in .NET Core:

```
extern "C" int32_t Bridge_OpenFile(char* filename) {
    // you can do some C++ calls here
    return 0;
}
```

using

```
[DllImport("my.dylib")]
private static extern int Bridge_OpenFile([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string filename);
```

Another trick: `DllImport` can be used with just `testmachw` since CoreCLR will add `lib` and `.dylib` automatically as part of the probing so you can have the same C# code and it will match `lib{foo}.dylib`, `lib{foo}.so` and `{foo}.dll` depending on the platform run on.