# return type of main() in C

Tags: c, program-entry-point, c11

Reading C11 Standard, when speaking about `main()` I read:

> 5.1.2.2.1 "...[main] shall be defined with a return type of int".
>   5.1.2.2.3 "...If the return type is not compatible with int,..."

The latter suggest that I can define `main()` to return a non integer value.
How is it possible if main "shall" return int?

And also, "The implementation declares no prototype for this function" gives freedom to use a non-integer return type?
Why immediately after says: "[main] shall be defined with a return type of int"?

Comment: further readings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489012/does-c-have-a-standard-abi + you should read something about the ABIs defined by the platform of choice.

Answer (score 4):

I have the impression that the sentence

> or in some other implementation-defined manner.

leads to confusion here. *implementation-defined* is the C standard jargon for *defined and  documented* by the compiler provider. This doesn't mean that the programmer is free to chose an arbitrary prototype for `main`. It means that he *may* use a different prototype if his compiler documentation foresees it.

The only other platform specific return type I know of is `void`, which is allowed on some oldish platforms. For the arguments to `main`, I know of platforms that allow for a third parameter that passes a pointer to the environment.

Comment: I agree: "implementation-defined" means "defined and documented by the compiler".  I use gcc on Debian-6 and it accept "void main()" as well.  But probably the C11 standard wish to pose a limit to compilers when says that main must be of integer type.  So 'void main()', 'float main()', 'char *main()' and so on can be accepted (if implemented) by compilers, but they are not standard conforming. Do you think that this could be the right interpretation to the above sentences?

Answer (score 2):

The full quote says `If the return type is not compatible with int, the termination status returned to the host environment is unspecified.`

That means it's undefined behavior. When `main()` exits, the program is essentially terminating, and the return value of main will be used as the exit status of the program. Since on most systems programs can only return an integer as their exit status, the return value of main is used as that exit code. Returning a string or pointer or whatever means you're returning something that the calling environment can't deal with.

Comment: Yes, OP's concern is that this sentence might make you think that if it is "compatible with int" then all is well, but that's a looser requirement than that the type *is* `int` stated earlier.

Comment: Well, you could return a `char`, which is somewhat interchangeable with int. `return('a')` and `return(97)` should function about the same.

Comment: this kind of Undefined Behaviour shouldn't be a surprise, in `C` it's UB when you don't specify the return value for **any** function that doesn't return `void`, the thing is that some compilers are smart enough to put `return(0);` for you in your `main` if you forget to put it yourself, but in general this is what you can expect from all your functions if you don't do the right thing.

Comment: "The implementation declares no prototype for this function" means to me that I can write: "float main()"; but C11 also says that I must write "int main()".  So I'm confused.

Comment: @user2431763 I think that the language specs are leaving room for the ABIs here, you should read something about the C/C++ ABI, not everything that it's related to `C` is defined in the `C` specs ( it's strange but true ).

Comment: The C spec is leaving things open for systems that COULD potentially handle non-standard exit/return values. The fact that Windows/Unix/etc... all expects ints is irrelevant for C. You could create a completely custom OS that requires processes exit with a pointer. That's outside of C's purview however, so you can return whatever you want, as long as the execution environment can handle it.

Comment: @MarcB So "[main] shall be defined with a return type of int" should be removed.  Or "The implementation declares no prototype".  They seem in contrast.

Comment: @user2431763 you need to read **the entire sentence**, you're not allowed to pick out one phrase and ignore the context.

Comment: @hobbs What part of the sentence I missed?  It seems so clear to me!  Can you help me to find the right interpretation?  I did read many times the entire sentence but I'm still confused.

Comment: unspecific doesn't mean undefined in all cases. It is up to the compiler/platform implementation to define the use of the return value, anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

> The implementation declares no prototype for this function.

That is, there's no existing prototype; whether you define it as `int main(void)`, `int main (int argc, char *argv[])`, or in "some other implementation-defined manner", you won't be conflicting with some implicit prototype.

> or in some other implementation-defined manner.

If we read this as governing the return type as well, then there's no conflict with what comes later, because this basically says that the signature of `main` can be whatever you like, if it makes sense for the implementation — and later — but, if `main` returns `int` or something convertible to `int` then returning from `main` has to be equivalent to calling `exit` (since `exit` is declared `void exit(int)`).

One possible point against my reading, though, is that if this was the intent I would expect it to say that the behavior when the return type is not `int` is *implementation-defined*, rather than undefined.

Comment: If there is no prototype I can write "float main()"?  But C11 says I must write "int main()"!

Comment: @user2431763 yes, you can write `float main()`, and it might even do something useful if your compiler allows for it, but probably not. If you read my answer you'll see that I'm arguing that it *doesn't* say you must write `int main()`.

Comment: So "It shall be defined with a return type of int" what means?

Comment: @user2431763 the signature is `int main(void)` or `int main(int, char *[])` or *something else as provided by the implementation*.