# What are the semantics of structure padding/packing in the Linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, padding, memory-alignment

I am interested in the semantics of structure padding and packing, specifically in relation to the structures returned from the Linux kernel.

For example, if a program+stdlib is compiled so structure padding doesn't take place, and a kernel is compiled with so structure padding *does* take place (Which IIRC is the default for GCC anyway), surely the program cannot run due to the structures returned from the kernel being garbage from it's point of view.

What about if the compiler in question changed it's padding semantics over time, surely the same problem is likely to crop up. The structures defined in `/usr/include/linux/*` and `/usr/include/asm-generic/*` do not appear to be packed, so they depend on the compiler used and the alignment semantics of said compiler, right?

But I can take a binary compiled years ago on a different computer with different memory alignment requirements and presumably different padding semantics, and run it on my modern computer and it appears to work fine.

**How does it not see garbage? Is this just pure luck? Do compiler authors (like say, TCC and the like) take care to copy GCC's structure padding semantics? How is this potential problem dealt with in the real world?**

Answer (score 1):

> The structures defined in `/usr/include/linux/*` and
>   `/usr/include/asm-generic/*` do not appear to be packed, so they
>   depend on the compiler used and the alignment semantics of said
>   compiler, right?

That's not true, generally. Here is an example from GCC on 64-bit Ubuntu (`/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/stat.h`):

```
struct stat {
        __kernel_ulong_t        st_dev;
        __kernel_ulong_t        st_ino;
        __kernel_ulong_t        st_nlink;

        unsigned int            st_mode;
        unsigned int            st_uid;
        unsigned int            st_gid;
        unsigned int            __pad0;
        __kernel_ulong_t        st_rdev;
        __kernel_long_t         st_size;
        __kernel_long_t         st_blksize;
        __kernel_long_t         st_blocks;      /* Number 512-byte blocks allocated. */

        __kernel_ulong_t        st_atime;
        __kernel_ulong_t        st_atime_nsec;
        __kernel_ulong_t        st_mtime;
        __kernel_ulong_t        st_mtime_nsec;
        __kernel_ulong_t        st_ctime;
        __kernel_ulong_t        st_ctime_nsec;
        __kernel_long_t         __unused[3];
};
```

See `__pad0`? `int` is generally 4 bytes, but `st_rdev` is `long`, which is 8 bytes, so it must be 8-byte aligned. However, it is preceded by 3 ints = 12 bytes, so a 4-byte `__pad0` is added.

Essentially, the implementation of stdlib takes care to hard-code its ABI.

**BUT** that isn't true for all APIs. Here is `struct flock` (from the same machine, `/usr/include/asm-generic/fcntl.h`) used by the `fcntl()` call:

```
struct flock {
    short   l_type;
    short   l_whence;
    __kernel_off_t  l_start;
    __kernel_off_t  l_len;
    __kernel_pid_t  l_pid;
    __ARCH_FLOCK_PAD
};
```

As you can see, there is no padding between `l_whence` and `l_start`. And indeed, for the following C program, saved as `abi.c`:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct flock fl;
    int fd;

    fd = open("y", O_RDWR);
    memset(&fl, 0xff, sizeof(fl));
    fl.l_type = F_RDLCK;
    fl.l_whence = SEEK_SET;
    fl.l_start = 200;
    fl.l_len = 1;
    fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &fl);
}
```

We get:

```
$ cc -g -o abi abi.c && strace -e fcntl ./abi
fcntl(3, F_SETLK, {l_type=F_RDLCK, l_whence=SEEK_SET, l_start=200, l_len=1}) = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
$ cc -g -fpack-struct -o abi abi.c && strace -e fcntl ./abi
fcntl(3, F_SETLK, {l_type=F_RDLCK, l_whence=SEEK_SET, l_start=4294967296, l_len=-4294967296}) = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

As you can see, the fields following `l_whence` are indeed garbage.

Moreover, [C has no ABI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4490480/10678955), and so this fragile compatibility relies on implementation playing nice. `struct stat` above assumes that the compiler wouldn't insert extra random padding.

ANSI C says:

> There may also be unnamed padding at the end of a structure or union, as necessary to achieve the appropriate alignment were the structure or union to be a member of an array.

There's no wording on how padding *may* be inserted in the middle of a struct for reasons other than alignment, however there's also:

> Implementation-defined behavior
>
> Each implementation shall document its behavior in each of the areas listed in this section. The following are implementation-defined:
>
> ...
>
> The padding and alignment of members of structures. This should present no problem unless binary data written by one implementation are read by another.

On my Ubuntu machine, both the compiler and the standard library come from GCC, so they interoperate smoothly. Clang wants to grow, so it's compatible with GNU libc. Everyone is just playing nice, most of the time.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I hadn't yet read the `stat` definition. Surely though since `struct stat` is not designated as `__attribute(packed)` then there's a slim chance that the compiler could add extra padding _between_ the padding elements?

Comment: Correct. C does not guarantee "no holes", and ANSI C literally says "This should present no problem unless binary data written by one implementation are read by another."