# A static C lib compiled with a C standard can work with program with another C standard?

Tags: c, gcc, clang, static-libraries, compiler-optimization

As I said I want to know if a static C lib compiled with a C standard can work with a program with another C standard (example: C11 static lib with C89 program).

I know compilers don't always produce compatible code between each other, and I suppose that the same compiler will produce compatible code between two standards (tested with GCC, no problem)... But is it a rule that I can assume is true?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4489012

Comment: If the libraries are produced for the same platform — the o/s on the hardware — then it is rare indeed for there to be a problem.  On macOS, I occasionally get a warning about some code having been compiled for a different o/s interface than the current one, but that's only a warning.  You can basically assume it is true, and be very surprised if you run across a counter-example.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So if I resume: std C version is used by compiler only to enable some features and optimization but doesn't affect compatibility between two binary file .. So in theory I can compile in same program a .c with different C version than others ... that it ?

Comment: Your mileage may vary.  If you link a library that relied on features such as `threads` or `thread local storage` with a main and libraries from an earlier feature set, you are likely to have problems.  More recent feature sets may have implicit dependencies on the C Runtime Library (crt) that are not explicit in the C Library (libc).