# What determines NumPy default integer precision?

Tags: python, numpy, integer, precision

```
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO
data = StringIO("1 2 3\n 4 5 6")
np.genfromtxt(data, dtype=(int, float, int), names="a")

array([(1, 2.0, 3), (4, 5.0, 6)],
      dtype=[('a', '<i8'), ('f0', '<f8'), ('f1', '<i8')])
```

The above code is from NumPy official documentation. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html#setting-the-names

When I ran it on my local PC, the result was different.
The '<f8' in the second element was the same, but I got '<i4' at the first and the third elements instead of '<i8' as in the example.

What makes the differenct? I ran it on Windows 10 PC of i7-6700 CPU. Might it depend on the hardware?

Comment: It's very unlikely to depend on the hardware. It might depend on the OS, or Python version.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the documentation, the `int` type decays to the `np.int_` one which [is not portable between platforms](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html). It is likely equal to `np.int32` on x86-64 Windows machines and `np.int64` on x86-64 Linux ones for example. Indeed, the size of default native integers is defined by the C ABI. The thing is [there is no standard C ABI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489012/does-c-have-a-standard-abi) but many ones each related to a set of platforms. The OS, the processor architecture and the compiler are the three parameters that generally define the ABI. A part of the ABI for the target platform defines the [data model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models). There are many of them, even for 64-bit systems, but only 2 are widely used nowadays: LLP64 and LP64. Based on this, we can conclude that the default Numpy integer size is:

```
32-bit on 64-bit Windows when using a standard MinGW build
64-bit on 64-bit Windows when using a non-standard Cygwin build
64-bit on most 64-bit Unix-like systems (eg. Linux, macOS, BSD)
32-bit on all 32-bit mainstream processors
```

It is generally better to **specify the size of the type** so to avoid platform dependent issues (eg. overflows) and better control memory usage of your program on different platforms it can be executed.