# Using C wrapper of C++ code for ABI stability?

Tags: c++, c, abi

In his [talk](https://youtu.be/By7b19YIv8Q) Jason Turner proposed to break the C++ ABI to keep the language moving forward. He also mentioned that if needed due to compatibility reasons, C++ ABI changes can be isolated by wrapping a C++ library into a C library.

A relevant screenshot at 27:30:

[image: C wrapper illustration]

Here "BinaryLibrary" and "Old C++ stdlib" use an old ABI, and "NewExecutable" uses a hypothetical updated ABI.

As far as I understand, this works since old C++ ABI of "BinaryLibrary" gets baked into a separate binary with a more stable interface.

But what makes C a good alternative? Can't its ABI change as well?

Comment: We have seen some C++ ABI changes the last year. That requires that we need to recompile all and everything. Sound horrible! Really? No! Typically we do some system updates from time to time and in fact every system update comes with a compiler update and all code is recompiled. A ABI change is a big step, no question. But we have already had some in the past. Introducing a wrapper seems to be not a solution for the problem as the new ABI must introduce new features. And I can't believe that a wrapper can fulfill all of them. That shifts ABI changes to wrapper changes... did this help?

Comment: @Klaus Yep.  How does this fix things?  With that C++ binary library inside a C wrapper, you're still dependent on the C++ run time libraries.  And if that "new executable" uses C++ in any way, it'll be linking in the **new** C++ run time libraries with the new ABI.  And it's pretty much impossible to mix multiple C++ run time libraries in the same executable.  Oh yeah - forcing recompiles **is** pretty horrible.  Large scale, **stable** systems that **work** don't live in the "I'll just run `yum update -y` on my production systems and recompile.  Gee, I hope it works." world.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can the C ABI change?  Well, not easily.  There have been occasional changes on some platforms, but so many systems and languages are built using the C ABI as a public interface that it has to be quite stable.  Many languages have a C [FFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface) which allows them to call C functions, and changing the C ABI would break those.  And the C ABI is a common way of interacting with the operating system, e.g. to open files or send messages, so it's used by many language implementations (e.g. interpreters and standard libraries).

Note that the C ABI is not part of the C standard.  Each platform or system can [define its own C ABI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4489090/4323).  So while it tends to be stable over time on a given platform, it is not consistent across all platforms.