How you can link a Rust library with C/C++ and wasm-bindgen for the wasm32-unknown-unknown target?
Title.
What are the specific steps to compile and link C/C++ and Rust under the same WASM binary for wasm32-unknown-unknown while using wasm-bindgen?
Context

wasm32-unknown-emscripten is a legacy target and seldom maintained by one part-time person, but until recently, it was the only target capable of compiling and linking libraries that use both Rust and C.
The Rust+WASM community largely moved towards the wasm32-unknown-unknown target with close collaboration with the wasm-bindgen project. A big part of the Rust+WASM ecosystem, including winit and wgpu gravitates towards that. There's good support and documentation all around.

Problem
The Rust compiler used to produce an incompatible C ABI for the wasm32-unknown-unknown target, that does not follow the specs-compliant clang's C ABI.
As wasm-bindgen depends on the Rust compiler, it also produced a WASM binary that was fundamentally incompatible and could not be linked together with binaries created by compliant C compilers.
Current State of the Ecosystem
There has been significant progress towards a solution. In April 2024, the Rust compiler team introduced a perma-unstable --wasm_c_abi flag that tells the compiler to produce compliant C ABI for WASM targets, and wasm-bindgen started to support compliant C ABI starting from version 0.2.88. This is the relevant tracking issue.
This flag is available in nightly Rust and will be removed in a future version, where the compiler will produce compliant C ABI by default.

first lesson of C, there is no C ABI :p

@Stargateur Thanks for mentioning it; this SO question gives context https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489012/does-c-have-a-standard-abi. I should probably edit the phrase "specs-compliant" since there is no standard C ABI. Any suggestion? Maybe "compatible with Clang's C ABI for WASM"?

Up until April 2024, you needed to use wasm32-unknown-emscripten or wasm32-wasi targets to link C and Rust under the same binary.
Now that the Rust compiler team Merged a PR introducing the perma-unstable wasm_c_abi flag, it's now possible to compile Rust+C for the wasm32-unknown-unknown target with Rust nightly and use wasm-bindgen with external C dependencies. This will be the default behavior in the near future.
Here's a minimal example of a Rust+C WASM lib.
The build process boils down to:
export RUSTFLAGS="--cfg=web_sys_unstable_apis --Z wasm_c_abi=spec"
cargo +nightly build --target=wasm32-unknown-unknown --release

cp target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/hello.rlib hello.a

clang \
    --target=wasm32 \
    -c \
    -o world.o \
    world.c

wasm-ld \
    --no-entry \
    --export-all \
    -o hello_world.wasm \
    hello.a \
    world.o


Just saw you deleted your answer on my question. Hope you weren't offended by my pushback on it, it's just my question was specifically focused on Emscripten as I needed other Emscripten features more than just using it as a C compiler, so posting a new question was a great idea!

So is this answer saying to rename an .rlib to an .a? That seems a little weird, can't you just compile directly to an .a? I don't know if it's worth mentioning, but simple functions that only passed numbers would probably already work without the new flag?

"I'll create my own question with blackjack and hookers" LOL. No offense taken. Your question was specifically about emscripten, so creating a dedicated one for the unknown target actually makes sense.

The renaming to .a part came from a PR to eliminate the intermediate step of transpiling to LLVM IR, which was my original solution. I also successfully built it with the cc crate, I'll edit the answer later to mention it.

I'm just wondering why you're not setting crate-type = ["staticlib"] in the first place.

When I use crate-type = ["staticlib"] and use the .a file directly, I get a bunch of warnings similar to: wasm-ld: warning: r_maths.a: archive member '45c91108d938afe8-absvdi2.o' is neither Wasm object file nor LLVM bitcode. This doesn't happen with rlib. I noticed you commented on the original PR by Surma, maybe you could ask him there. His last commit message in that PR was "omg rlib is the solution".

I didn't think that .rlibs were designed for use with other languages. It's cool that it works, but can it be relied on? Whereas .as should work (and does for wasm32-unknown-emscripten). If it doesn't for wasm32-unknown-unknown then maybe that's a bug? On the other hand, if it's only a warning, maybe nothing is actually wrong with it? Rust could be adding some metadata or something that can be ignored.

The .wasm file is compiled with the warnings, but it seems it doesn't export the C symbols for some reason and it breaks at runtime. As far as I know, the only difference between .a and .rlib is that '.rlib' adds some metadata, but I agree relying on it for interfacing with other languages is weird.
