# Does a standard C++ ABI have real performance penalty?

Tags: c++, llvm, abi

I think that every profession C++ developer knows how difficult is write a shared library in C++ that works across different compilers. This is due the fact that C++ (and C) doesn't have a standard ABI. The major reason for the absence of the ABI seems performance penalty.

Looking at LLVM and Clang this myth seems falling down. Clang and LLVM gives great possibility of performance optimization.

So does a standardized C++ ABI (and why not a module system) decrease C++ performance?

Comment: "The major reason for the absence of the ABI seems performance penalty." [citation needed]

Comment: What did you look at in llvm and clang that tells you the ABI does not affect performance? The major reason for not having a standard ABI is that the ABI maps between the generated code constructs and the hardware, and the hardware is very different in intel, amd, power, sparc... processors

Comment: There is a C ABI - hence a C++ would  be possible, IF, compiler manufactures could agree to one!

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas LLVM is a virtual machine infrastructure that doesn’t provide any of the high-level features you’d find in something like the Java or .NET virtual machines, including garbage collection and an object model. This psedu-code is later converted in machine code

Comment: http://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html

Comment: Have you profiled the code?

Comment: Actually, I believe this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083060/what-could-c-c-lose-if-they-defined-a-standard-abi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What could C/C++ "lose" if they defined a standard ABI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083060/what-could-c-c-lose-if-they-defined-a-standard-abi)

Comment: @DieterLücking they have just on an OS specific basis. There is the Windows C++ ABI and there is the Itanium ABI. AFAIK those are the only two ABIs in use. It is worth noting that both have implementation versions on both platforms that may vary with the compiler versions.

Comment: @Dieter "There is a C ABI". Where? What standards body defines it?