# how to change '-march=native' compile flag added by PCL in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, pcl

I'm new to cmake, recently, my program cannot run on another device and I find that reason is compile flag `-march=native` silently added (found `PCL` library do it), I verify it by modifying value of `-march` from **native** to **x86-64** `CXX_FLAGS` in ***flags.make*** (hacking this file because I cannot find a way to change it within cmake file by setting CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS or add_compile_options).

One word, that compile flag `-march=native` is added by `PCL` library by find_package.

***QUESTION***

I want change it to `-march=x86-64` in cmake, How to do it?

Ps: Tried adding `-march=x86-64` to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` or `add_compile_options`, not working by inspecting ***flags.make*** in which `CXX_FLAGS` is:

```
CXX_FLAGS = -march=x86-64 -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC -march-native -msse4.2 -mfpmath=sse -std=gnu++14
```

and the letter `-march=native` wins.

Comment: "I want change it to `-march=x86-64` in cmake, How to do it? - Find out how **exactly** PCL adds `-march=native` flag. If it does that via variable `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, then you may try to modify that variable (but note about variables scoping rules). If PCL adds the flag to some property, then you may try modify that property. CMake doesn't give you a control over **combined** compiler flags. You need to find out which part (variable, properties) contains the flag in the question, and operate on that part (or on the part which comes after it).

Comment: Another thing to consider: if PCL's CMake configuration (found by `find_package(PCL)`) is setting `-march=native` and other SSE flags, it suggests the PCL on your machine was built with those flags enabled. Compiling your own program with different flags also [risks binary compatibility issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58019869/431033). The safest solution may be to recompile PCL with the appropriate flags for the machine you want to run the program on.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks @Tsyvarev and @Lack for useful suggestions.

I solved that problem by recompile `PCL` from stretch by adding `-DPCL_ENABLE_MARCHNATIVE=False -DPCL_ENABLE_SSE=False ..` as following command:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DPCL_ENABLE_MARCHNATIVE=False -DPCL_ENABLE_SSE=False ..
```

This can eliminate `-march=native` from final flags, which will work on other devices and I test it.

Besides, someone says only `-DPCL_ENABLE_SSE=False` is needed due to mine `PCL` version is `1.10.1` and `PCL_ENABLE_MARCHNATIVE` was not introduced yet. But I haven't tried this.